# Data on average annual hours worked by persons engaged

Tags: labor-economics, economic-growth, data-request, productivity

In Penn World Table 10.0 (source: https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/productivity/pwt/pwt-releases/pwt100), the avh (average annual hours worked by persons engaged) figures are missing for many countries.

Where can I find the more complete data on this variable for the period of 1991-2019? I need the data for the following countries:

Albania
Algeria
Armenia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahrain
Belarus
Bhutan
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Brunei Darussalam
Djibouti
Egypt
Ethiopia
Georgia
Iran (Islamic Republic of)
Iraq
Jordan
Kazakhstan
Kenya
Kuwait
Kyrgyzstan
Lao People's DR
Lebanon
Mongolia
Montenegro
Morocco
Mozambique
Nepal
North Macedonia
Oman
Qatar
Republic of Moldova
Saudi Arabia
Serbia
Sudan
Syrian Arab Republic
Tajikistan
Tunisia
Turkmenistan
U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland
Ukraine
United Arab Emirates
Uzbekistan
Yemen

Also, where can I find the data on average annual salaries by countries for the period of 1991-2019.

I checked out WDI, OECD, ILO and other databases, but could not find the data.